# What is the tone for 少 in 老少边穷地区?

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronunciation, tones

I hear Mr. Xi Jinping in his address to villagers spoke 老少边穷地区 in the fourth tone (i.e., 少 as 绍）, but I think he might have made a mistake here, out of instincts, without any real understanding.

Comment: Not a mistake, No one say 老少(shao3)边穷, since 少 is preceded by a third tone, it is easy to say shao4

Comment: It is definitely a mistake if pronounced as shao4.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s 现代汉语规范词典’s entry:

> 老少边穷
>
> PY lǎo-shǎo-biān-qióng
>
> 老解放区､少数民族地区､边疆地区和穷困地区的合称。
>
> 注意 “少”这里不读shào, 不当“年少”讲。

Answer (score 2):

It should be pronounced as the 3rd tone, i.e. `shǎo`. Because `少` in [老少边穷地区](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%80%81%E5%B0%91%E8%BE%B9%E7%A9%B7%E5%9C%B0%E5%8C%BA) refers to 少数民族自治地区.

> 老少边穷地区：主要指革命老区、少数民族自治地区、陆地边境地区和欠发达地区。

BTW: [老少](http://www.zdic.net/c/1/149/321548.htm) (pronounced as `lǎo shào`) is another word which means `the old and the young`. So pronouncing `老少边穷` as `lǎo shào biān qióng` would be quite confusing.

Reference: [“老少边穷”的“少”怎么读？](http://hanyu.iciba.com/a/20090806/1851.shtml)